# Redirecting read to output

Tags: bash, command-line, posix

I have a piece of code for changing the first piece of a space-delineated database:

```
if [[ "$(cut -d ' ' -f 1 commandnames.txt | grep -F "$2")" == "" ]] ; then
    while read -r name rest; do
    if [[ "$1" == "$name" ]]
    then echo "$2 $rest"
    else echo "$name $rest"; fi
    done < commandnames.txt > commandnames.txt
    echo "Renamed $1 to $2."              
fi
```

However, the `> commandnames.txt` does not work, instead clearing the file. It works fine when the output is to stdout. I tried putting the `while` loop until the stdout redirection into a subshell, but it didn't seem to work. Any ideas as to why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When executing

```
while read -r name rest; do
...
done < commandnames.txt > commandnames.txt
```

this is what happens:

1. `< commandnames.txt`: Open "commandnames.txt" for reading
2. `> commandnames.txt`: Open "commandnames.txt" for writing and truncate it.
3. `while read -r name rest`: Read a line at a time until stdin is empty

Since step 2 truncates the file, the loop runs 0 times, so there's nothing to write. The file is therefore empty.

The fix is simple: avoid deleting the input before you read it.

You can do this by writing to a temporary file, and then overwriting your original when you're done:

```
while read -r name rest; do
...
done < commandnames.txt > tmpfile && mv tmpfile commandnames.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

> However, the `> commandnames.txt` does not work, instead clearing the
>   file.

Saying `> outfile` would *truncate*<sup>1</sup> the file to begin with.

As such, your attempts to read from the same file would yield no results.

Redirect output to a different file and `mv` or `cp` it later as the need might be.

---

<sup>1</sup> Quoting from the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirecting-Output) (emphasis mine):

> Redirection of output causes the file whose name results from the
>   expansion of word to be opened for writing on file descriptor *n*, or
>   the standard output (file descriptor 1) if *n* is not specified. If the
>   file does not exist it is created; **if it does exist it is truncated to
>   zero size**.

Comment: It works when I output to stdout; that's not the problem. I'll edit the original question. Edit: Ok, I saw your edit. Is the truncation occuring mid-command?

Comment: @bb010g Yes, it doesn't work __because__ you attempt to redirect output to the __same file__.

Answer (score 1):

You wont manage to do this without some kind of temporary storage.

If you are 100% sure that your commandnames.txt file won't ever be too big, you could read the file into a variable and then parse the contents of the variable

```
GV_LINES=$(cat test_lines.txt)
while read LV_LINE
do
  echo "${LV_LINE}_suffix"
done <<< "${GV_LINES}" > test_lines.txt
```

else look at the mktemp or tempfile commands to create temporary files